# Equilibrium point of first order ODE has smooth dependence on parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a first order, one dimensional ODE that depends on a parameter $a$, $$x' = f_a(x).$$ I have an equilibrium point $x_0$, so $f_a (x_0) = 0$. And I'm given that $f_a'(x) \neq 0$.

What I'm trying to prove is that when the parameter $a$ varies by a sufficiently small amount $\epsilon$, there is still an equilibrium point to the new ODE $$x' = f_{a+\epsilon}(x),$$ and furthermore that the equilibrium point is smoothly dependent on the parameter - that is, it can be given as a C^1 function of $\epsilon$ which equals $x_0$ when $\epsilon = 0$.

I thought about reformulating it as a higher dimensional problem (treating $a$ as another spatial variable), but that just made the equations more complex. And I tried solving it as if it were a non-autonomous ODE with $a$ as the time parameter, in the hopes of using some results about the existence of solutions in a neighborhood of the initial condition, but none of the results I have learned of so far work for nonlinear, non-autonomous equations.

I'm thinking there must be some way to do something with the linearization, but nothing is coming to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Implicit Function Theorem.

Write $f_a(x)=F(x,a)$. The equation
$$
F(x,\lambda)=0
$$
has the solution $(x_0,a)$ and
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \lambda}(x_0,a)\ne0.
$$
The implicit function theorem implies that there exist $\epsilon>0$ and a smooth function $\phi:(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined on a neighborhood of $a$ such that
$$
F(\phi(\lambda),\lambda)=0,\quad \phi(a)=x_0.
$$
That is, you can solve for $x$ as a function of $\lambda$.